# freeze layer parameters in Flux.jl alternative

Tags: julia, flux

I am trying to train a generative model for MNIST. To speed up the process, I plan to use the latent space layers of an already pretrained discriminator and incorporate them into my model. This approach should allow me to train in a lower-dimensional space. However, I have the following syntax question: I know it's possible to train only certain parameters with `Flux.params`, but in all my models, I'm using the `withgradient(neural_network)` do ... syntax. Is there any way to specify directly which layers you want to freeze when building a neural network?

Comment: The documented way to specify this is to mutate the optimiser state, `s = Flux.setup(...)` then `freeze!(s.layers[2])` or something, as here: https://fluxml.ai/Optimisers.jl/dev/#Frozen-Parameters .